# How do I use axios in an AWS Synthetics Canary script?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, axios, amazon-cloudwatch-synthetics

I am writing an AWS Synthetics Canary script in JavaScript. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries_WritingCanary_Nodejs.html) that I am using to write the script.

So far, I have written a whole script, but I need to use the axios library at some point because I must call an API to obtain a token, before starting to test our internal APIs. I do not want to use `executeHttpStep` because I do not want to log any issues with this API, as the purpose of this canary is not to test the API to obtain the token.

However, I am having trouble importing axios, I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'axios'Require stack:- /opt/nodejs/node_modules/index.js- /var/task/index.js- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js- /var/runtime/Runtime.js- /var/runtime/index.js Stack: Error: Cannot find module 'axios'Require stack:- /opt/nodejs/node_modules/index.js- /var/task/index.js- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js- /var/runtime/Runtime.js- /var/runtime/index.js at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:15) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:27) at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:19) at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:107:18) at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/index.js:4:15) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:14) at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:819:12) at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:19)
```

It cannot recognize axios.

I now want to follow the steps in the documentation which explains how to use external dependencies:

> // Require any dependencies that your script needs
>
> // Bundle additional files and dependencies into a .zip file with folder structure
>
> // nodejs/node_modules/additional files and folders

I am a bit confused by these instructions.

- If I understand correctly: to use library `axios`, I need to put that folder inside `nodejs/node_modules/`, then zip it, then in the code I should do: `const axios = require('.nodejs/node_modules/axios');` is that correct?
- Do I need to put the zip file at the same level as the canary script JS file (like in the same folder)?
- Do I also need to have the canary inside this `nodejs/node_modules/` folder structure?